# Best technique to use memset() in C

Tags: c

```
#define MAX 100

struct bs{
 int ab;
 int ac;
}be;
struct s{
 be b;
 int c;
 int d;
 int e;
}fe;

int a[MAX];
fe f;
```

**Technique 1**:

```
f.b.ab = a;
memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
f.b.ac = MAX;
```

**Technique 2**:

```
f.b.ab = a;
f.b.ac = MAX;
memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
```

**Technique 3**:

```
memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
f.b.ab = a;
f.b.ac = MAX;
```

which is the best technique to follow and why?

Comment: I strongly advise you to use variable names that are more descriptive.

Comment: You know why the compiler prevents you from having different stuff with the same name ? Because it can't tell what you mean. Just like I can't tell what `a` means, since you have `int a[MAX];` and `f a`.

Comment: you can't declare two different variables the same name! you've got to `a`s

Comment: Has the OP changed this code, or am I missing something? At this moment `int a[MAX];` and `typeof f.b.ab` is `int`, so `f.b.ab = a;` is not legal C. What is meant here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technique 3:**

```
memset(&a,0,sizeof(a));
f.b.ab = a;
f.b.ac = MAX;
```

because both `a` and `fb.b.ab` will have clear memories with only **one** `memset()` call. Any other kind of optimization you might been hoping for is insignificant.

Comment: but why cant we just intialise the structure variables without doing a memset

Comment: The problem with `struct` is that it allocates a certain amount of space in memory, but there's no guarantee that the memory block you receive is clean. That's why we must do this by manually. Another option, is to initialize/clear the members of the struct one by one. **Pick your poison**!

Comment: @karlphillip, how can you say that anything is correct in that code? I was even tempted to give you a -1.

Comment: @JensGustedt I never said the code is correct. I understood the core of the question (where his doubt was) and I answered just that.

Comment: well I see at the core of the question is that he doesn't know what initialization is. how do you read his intentions of initializing an supposed `int` (the field `ab` of what?) with a pointer to `int`? As it is written the ordering of the assignments is completely irrelevant, even if the types were correct. The compiler could reorder as it pleases.

Comment: I think he does know what initialization is since in another question he implemented a linked list. Now, the order of the calls here do matter! Let's assume his type declarations were correct, ok? On technique 1, since `a` was declared and not initialized, doing `f.b.ab = a;` would copy the garbage from `a` to `f.b.ab` and after that `memset()` would clear `a`. So `f.b.ab` would have garbage and `a` would be clean. On technique 2, same problem. On technique 3, `a` is cleared and then it gets copied to `f.b.ab`, meaning both would be cleared.

Comment: Of course, he still needs to perform the initialization of the other members of `f`.

Comment: You guys are making me doubt my sanity (no biggie :-). Has the OP changed this code, or am I missing something? At this moment `int a[MAX];` and `typeof f.b.ab` is `int`, so `f.b.ab = a;` is not legal C, and what is `&a` supposed to mean, `&a[0]` or `a` or something else? What is assumed the OP means?

Comment: The only problem is that the OP didn't test his code and wrote it out of the blue trying to get some help on this issue. It's not a well formulated question, the code has problems, I agree with you guys. The fact that the code is not solid really bothers but at the end of the day what the wanted to know sounded very simple. This is my last comment on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above. The best would be:

```
int a[MAX] = { 0 };
fe f = { .b.ab = a, .b.ac = MAX };
```

Comment: Indeed, but I'm assuming (based on his using it as one) that he just forgot to write `typedef`.

Comment: he forgot a lot of things, it seems :) and `ab` is `int` and `a` is converted to `int*`, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

None. What you probably mean for a start is `memset(a,0,sizeof(a));`

`a` is an array that is converted to a pointer in that context, no need to take the address. (The C FAQ has more information about arrays and pointers.)

Then for the rest of it you should revise your basic knowledge of C before you go further

```
struct s{
 be b;
 int c;
 int d;
 int e;
}fe;


fe f;
```

Here the structure type is `struct s` and `fe` is a variable of that type. So the last line here makes no sense at all.